# Intersecting raster layer with grid to find average within each cell in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, intersect

I have a raster of population density and would like to intersect it with a polygon layer and have each polygon carry the average for the underlying raster cells. How would I go about this? I feel like they need to be intersected but what else?

[image]

Comment: the "negative dimensions not allowed" error might be a clue.. can you edit your question to include that message and the extra steps you took to get that message? (also, where did you get the raster data - is it SEDAC GPW ?).

Comment: Yep this is SEDAC GPW. Fixed by downloading from original source. For some reason in raster I was provided coordinates had been changed to match pixels of raster.

Answer (score 3):

This is basic **Zonal statistics** task.

You can find this in menu: `Raster -> Zonal statistics -> Zonal statistics`. This creates new attribute in polygon layer, carrying chosen calculation.

[image]

Other option is use *Zonal statistics* function from *Processing toolbox*

Comment: Except I want an average within each one of my custom cells. I'm still confused how I would go about intersecting the two different layers. Also I have no option for zonal stats (assume that would be raster calculator)

Comment: try **Processing > Toolbox** and type **zonal** into the  search bar, it's under QGIS Geoalgorithms (I'm on QGIS 2.18, and the option seems to have been removed from the Raster menu). You'll want to select average and/or median. Zonal stats does all the intersecting for you.

Comment: I'm getting error saying "negative dimensions not allowed". I know how to fix this for my vector layer but what's the best way of editing this for a raster layer?

Comment: The raster menu option is dependent on built-in plugin **Zonal statistics plugin**, maybe its just deactivated. Both options (menu and processing toolbox) works fine for me in 2.18. @Simon sorry I don't know whats causing this error.